# Run Time Error While using upgraded openssl-1.0.1c on android ICS

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I am trying to upgrade openssl from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1c on android(ICS).
while I was successfully able to cross compile it(for arm).
I get an error when i try to run openssl binary on target with upgraded libcrypto.so library.

Following is the error:
unexpected reloc type 0x03 for libcrypto.so

I am doing something wrong or are there any compilation flags that I am missing???
I have tried compiling openssl with -fPIC but that didn't help either.

PS : I am using android google tv branch.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the native Android build system to build OpenSSL. Don't know the details offhand, but they might be using special options as well as defines to turn things on/off. Get the AOSP source and replace the OpenSSL files with 1.0.1c. Also there is a separate build configuration over at the Guardian Project's Github if you don't want to build the whole thing (which is safer): https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android

Comment: hi nicholay,                 
thanks for the reply.
But replacing/merging the following assembly files from the old release did the trick.
aes/asm/aes-armv4.s 
bn/asm/armv4-mont.s 
sha/asm/sha1-armv4-large.s 
sha/asm/sha256-armv4.s 
sha/asm/sha512-armv4.s